# get the import directory in C

Tags: c, portable-executable

I want to get to the DLL imports.

What I have done:
I use CreateFile(), CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile().
Once I get the pointer to the starting address of the mapped view, I get a IMAGE_NT_HEADERS struct, a IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER struct and a IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER struct.

```
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pnhs;
PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER poh;
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER psh;
```

I had no problem getting other information from these. Now I got to the first tricky part, the import table.

I suspect there is something wrong with my logic:
I go to the Optional Header for the Data Directories, in this case poh->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT] where I can get it's RVA (VirtualAddress field). 
I check if the Size field is > 0 (because if it's 0 I have no imports).
Now I should get a pointer to a IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR struct. 
In order to do this I must find the file offset corresponding to the RVA.

```
for(i = 0; i < pnhs->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++){
    if(rva >= psh->VirtualAddress && rva < (psh->VirtualAddress + psh->PointerToRawData)){
        // I find in which section my RVA is
        // rva = DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress
        fileOffset = rva - psh->VirtualAddress + psh->PointerToRawData; // I'm not fully confident that I understood this concept perfect
    }
    psh++; // get to the next header
    // I make a backup copy of psh before this for
}
```

Once I get the file offset I add it to the pointer returned by MapViewOfFile and at that address I should find an array of IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR structs (one for every imported DLL)?

It seems like I'm not getting to the right address for a struct of that type.

This must be done exclusively in C.

Comment: There's lots of code out there for parsing PE files. Have you checked how they do it? Have you read Matt Pietrek's articles on the subject?

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes. My main question here is what is wrong in the above logic (because it's obviously I have not understood some things). I don't want to look at some code that solves this problem just to solve this problem. I want to know what I did wrong in my code

Comment: Doesn't sound to me like you really want to work it our for yourself